# Javascript Function to hover over element?

Tags: javascript, html, console

I know we can click buttons with click() in console, but how do you hover over an element to reveal the tooltip that comes up when you hover your mouse over the icon?

Comment: Will it trigger built-in actions like tooltips, or just jQuery handlers?

Comment: @RyanWilson That's not showing the built-in browser tooltip, it's showing a DIV with `id="tooltip"`

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there a .mouseover() function like the click() function that I can just type into console in the form: element.mouseover() just like element.click()?

Comment: @JoeyChen I was wrong on my previous comment. If this is a tooltip from `html` using the `title` attribute, calling `mouseover` won't trigger it. Can you give more information as to how you are applying the tooltip?

Comment: @RyanWilson $(".ZyFrc").mouseover(); gives the error: VM1349:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mouseover is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: Similarly: $(".ZyFrc").trigger('mouseover')
VM1294:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).trigger is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: @JoeyChen That's because that is `jquery`, with plain `javascript` it would be: `const e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent('mouseover', false, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(e);`. Sorry for the confusion, I should have done a better job of reading your tags.

Comment: @RyanWilson No problem at all. I just tried this:  let asdf=document.querySelector('.ZyFrc'); then I did const e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');         e.initEvent('mouseover', false, true);         asdf.dispatchEvent(e); and it gives: VM8378:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'e' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Answer (score -2):

You can use `onmouseover()`
Check out some DOM event handlers
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: that isn't what I want to do. I want to simulate the mouse hovering over a div with a console script.

Answer (score -3):

The mouseover event occurs when the mouse pointer is over the selected element.

The mouseover() method triggers the mouseover event or attaches a function to run when a mouseover event occurs.

```html
<div onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)" 
style="background-color:#D94A38;width:120px;height:20px;padding:40px;">
Mouse Over Me</div>

<script>
function mOver(obj) {
  obj.innerHTML = "Thank You"
}

function mOut(obj) {
  obj.innerHTML = "Mouse Over Me"
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to simulate a mouseover, and mouseover() is not working

Comment: let i=document.querySelectorAll('.ZyFrc')
i.mouseover();
VM1393:2 Uncaught TypeError: i.mouseover is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:3
I am trying to hover over a div so that the tooltip shows and then I can use click() to simulate a click on it.
@Zia

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".ZyFrc").mouseover(function(){
   ...
  });
}
Try changing it to jQuery like

Comment: when I run the script in console I want it to hover over ZyFrc itself.

Comment: ZyFcr is id or class of your div tag?

Comment: it is the class. I may have not been clear earlier, but the purpose of the script I am writing is this: hover over div in class "ZyFcr", doing so, a button will appear, click the button, and click another button that comes after that. Do this for all divs in the class. Thanks!